# How can I add a command to the end of a target in Ant?

Tags: java, ant

I don't know much Ant. I found a good bit of code online, and I want to append it to the end of an already existing target that I cannot directly edit. How can I do this?

Java example (for clarity):

```
public methodName() {
  super.methodName();
  a++;
}
```

Comment: The code sample doesn't look like Ant - are you sure you posted the correct stuff?

Comment: It's Java, like I said. It demonstrates the same concept, but in a different language. I know Java, but not Ant.

Comment: Ant is XML based.  To add more processing to a target you simply add calls to the tasks you want to execute within the <target> and </target> tags, that's it.  Everything in between the tags is considered the code to execute for that target.  Target can also have dependencies that require another target be executed before the current target.   Hope this helps.  Having a hard time figuring out what you are trying to accompolish.

Comment: I would add code between the <target> tags, but I can't edit the target itself. It is imported and I can add extra targets, but I wanted to know if there was a way to "extend" an existing target.

Comment: Hard to extend existing targets if you can't edit the existing target.  You could possibly create a new target that 'dependsOn' this existing target.  That way, when you execute your new target, it must first run that target and then will run your new (separate) target.

Comment: So that will make it so that when the new target is run, the existing target is also auto-run?

Comment: Yes, let me write a small sample and will post an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a small sample Ant build file.  The default target is post.process.  This could be the processing you want to execute after the existing process is run.  I also added a target called 'around'.   This invokes a before target, then the existing target and lastly the process.process target.

```
<project name="Test Dependency" basedir="." default="post.process">

    <target name="existing.target" description="Existing target">
        <echo>Existing target that you cannot change</echo>
    </target>

    <target name="post.process"  description="new post processing " depends="existing.target">
        <echo>New target that runs after existing target</echo>
    </target>

    <target name="around"  description="processing around existing target" depends="before.process,existing.target,post.process"/>

    <target name="before.process" description="run before existing target">
       <echo>runs before existing target when target around called </echo>
    </target>

</project>.
```

Here's the result of running this file.  First just type ant or ant post.process.  Because the project tag defined post.process as the default target, it will be used if no target passed.

The you can run 'ant around without the quotes.  Below are the results.

```
Mikes-MacBook-Pro:J7 mike$ ant
Buildfile: build.xml

existing.target:
     [echo] Existing target that you cannot change

post.process:
     [echo] New target that runs after existing target

BUILD SUCCESSFUL
Total time: 0 seconds
Mikes-MacBook-Pro:J7 mike$ ant around
Buildfile: build.xml

before.process:
     [echo] runs before existing target when target around called 

existing.target:
     [echo] Existing target that you cannot change

post.process:
     [echo] New target that runs after existing target

around:
```